# Array posted as null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that this question has some alternatives in SO that have been answered, but none of these solutions worked for me.

I have an array of integers that I want to `POST` to a method via `AJAX`. But somehow the parameter is always `null` in the controller.

Here is my `JS`:

```
function addSelected(cID, pID) {
    var id, idList = [];
    $("#FilteredCategory_" + pID + "_" + cID + " .content ul li a").each(function () {
        id = parseInt(this.className.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''), 10);
        idList.push(id);
    });
    $.ajax('@Url.Action("SelectedAdd","Home")', {
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        data: idList,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

`POST` method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string SelectedAdd(ICollection<int> topicIds)
{
    string res = string.Empty;
    foreach (var id in topicIds)
    {
        res += $"Item in list: '{id}' \n ";
    }
    return res;
}
```

Any suggestions, why `topicIds` is always `nul`?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Show relevant HTML - click the `<>` snippet editor and give us a real example. Any console errors? Console log the idList

Comment: Just because your parameter in ajax request is different from `c#`'s method. Change from `data: idList` to `data: {topicIds: idList }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a name/value pair which matched the name of the parameter in your method. Change the ajax call to

```
$.ajax('@Url.Action("SelectedAdd","Home")', {
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    data: { topicIds: idList }, // change
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: what a dummy mistake. Thanks. If I have several parameters, should I just mention them via comma-separated name/value pair?

Comment: Yes (so long as they are simple properties - otherwise you would need to stringify the data and set the `contentType` to `application/json`) - e.g. `data: { id: someValue, topicIds: idList },`